# Django + ElasticSearch + Docker - Connection Timeout no matter what hostname I use

Tags: django, docker, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm having issues connecting with my Elasticsearch container since day 1.
First I was using elasticsearch as the hostname, then I've tried the container name web_elasticsearch_1, and finally I'd set a Static IP address to the container and passed it in my configuration file.

PYPI packages:

- django==3.2.9
- elasticsearch==7.15.1
- elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: local/Dockerfile
    image: project32439/python
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - local/python.env
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.10
```

**settings.py**

```
# Elasticsearch
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST = "172.18.0.10"
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT = 9200
```

**service.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{"host": settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST, "port": settings.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}],
    use_ssl=False,
    verify_certs=False,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
)
```

**traceback**

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.18.0.10', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1973ebd6d0>, 'Connection to 172.18.0.10 timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

Comment: Using the service name as the host should work `elasticsearch`, perhaps you need to expose the port?

Comment: In the docker-compose? I'll try that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Docker Compose uses a bridge network to provision inter-container communication. You can read more about this network at the Debian Wiki.

What matters for you, is that by default Docker Compose creates a hostname that equals the service name in the `docker-compose.yml` file. So update your file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: local/Dockerfile
    image: project32439/python
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - local/python.env
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

And now you can connect with `elasticsearch:9200` instead of `172.18.0.10` from your web container. For more info see this [article](https://medium.com/@datails/full-stack-development-with-docker-compose-c517ec826696).